# how can we populate picklist values from custom object in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I have a custom object(survey__c) and custom field which holds the picklists values of the month (month__c). i want to use these picklist values in vf page.... i am using a custom controller in vf page .....can anyone help in resolving this issue with an example .

**vf page :**

```
<apex:selectList id="Months" value="{!Survey__c.Month__c}" size="1" required="true">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!months}"/>        
</apex:selectList> 
<p/>
```

**controller :**

```
public List<SelectOption> getMonths()

{

  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();



   Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult =  Survey__c.Month__c.getDescribe();

   List<Schema.PicklistEntry> ple = fieldResult.getPicklistValues();



   for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : ple)

   {

      options.add(new SelectOption(f.getLabel(), f.getValue()));

   }       

   return options;

}
```

it is giving error as -

> Unknown property : 'CommunitySurveyContrller.Survey__c'

Comment: post your controller code and vf page. it's hard to guess what's causing your error

Comment: edited the code

Comment: are you using standardcontroller?

Comment: i am using a custom controller "CommunitySurveyContrller"

Comment: I think there is not variable defined (with get;set;) as Survey__c, which of-course you cannot define because identifiers cannot contain __. So I think your binding property is incorrect. You need to define a variable in your code and bind the selectlist to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming Survey__c is what you are trying to populate, you need to define a variable/property in your controller, i.e.:

`public Survey__c survey {get; set;}`

then in your constructor, instantiate it, i.e.:

`public CommunitySurveyContrller() {
      survey = new Survey__c();
}`

then in your VF page, access/connect it, i.e.:

`<apex:selectList id="Months" value="{!survey.Month__c}" size="1" required="true">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!months}"/>
</apex:selectList>`

hope this helps.